# Phonegap check internet connection

Tags: android, cordova, phonegap-build

How can i check the internet connection in cordova 3.0 build? Because i tried

```
function ondeviceready(){  checkconnection(); alert(navigator.connection.type); }
```

but it returns always 0.

I heard about jquery mobile but i don't know how to use it because i tried

```
 function checkconnection(){   alert(navigator.onLine);}
```

with jquery mobile library loaded but it returns always true.

This is happening on my smartphone and on AVD too.

Can someone help me?

Comment: Which platform are you testing this on?

Comment: did you add network connection plugin ?

Comment: Yes i added the plugin in config.xml because in phonegap build the plugins.xml files doesn't exists

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can check the connection like this:

```
function CheckConnection()
{
     if( !navigator.network )
     {
         // set the parent windows navigator network object to the child window
         navigator.network = window.top.navigator.network;
     }

    // return the type of connection found
   return ( (navigator.network.connection.type === "none" || navigator.network.connection.type === null || 
          navigator.network.connection.type === "unknown" ) ? false : true );
}
```

returns true for connection and false for no connectivity.

In Android Manifest, use the following permission:

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
```

Edit:
Handles windows in iframes as well. Added another permission.

Comment: It gives me the next error: "connection" doesn't exists for undefined..which means it doesn't recognize the method  network for navigatoe

Comment: What this mean?.. i mean i didn't use any of iframe html tag :-??

Comment: yes, I tried, the same error: "Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property  of undefined at file:///android_asset/www/index.html:29"

Comment: Added another permission to access the internet state. Check now

Comment: i have all this three permissions added : <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
 <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />  
 <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_PHONE_STATE" />  and is not working

Answer (score 1):

Hello Zvîncă Alin Ionuț,

Following Code should be work in phonegap for internet check...

```
var networkState = navigator.connection.type;
    if (networkState == Connection.NONE){
         alert('No Internet');      
    }else{
         alert('Internet Connection there');
    }
```

Application also needs permision to connect internet so add above line in config.xml.

```
<feature name="http://api.phonegap.com/1.0/network"/>
```

Comment: It says that Connection is not defined and the entire aplication failed. It's about Connection.NONE.

Comment: I think in your that page phonegap not loaded So first check phonegap loaded or not in your app?

Comment: Thank you so much for your help, its helped me to solve my connection check issue...

Comment: @ Piyush, i need to work this code when the internet connection is blocked while running my app.

Comment: @Shafips please specify your problem or post new question of your  problem so i can help you

Answer (score 1):

**Try This**  I wiil be work in phonegap for internet check.

```
//Check Internaet Connection.................................

  //If User is Online.................................

function onOnline() {               
            alert("Internet connected")
}

//If User is Offline....................................
document.addEventListener("offline", onOffline, false);
function onOffline() {
    alert("Internet not connected")

}
    document.addEventListener("online", onOnline, false);
```

Comment: I tried this too, but the event fire only if i lose the connection when i use the app.

Comment: @Zvîncă Alin Ionuț : Yes.. In this its works only if u loose connection . That means when u use app ; first it checks our device is online or not. Then what u expect ?

Comment: Yes, is what i'm expecting but it doesn't works. That events don't fire.

Comment: check my code now and try once again ! Hope u add cordova.js in ur html code. try to add your script file like                               <script type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8" src="cordova-2.7.0.js"></script>      
    <script type="text/javascript" src="script/jquery.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="script/jqm.js"></script>
      <script type="text/javascript" src="script/jquery.mobile.iscrollview.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="script/app.js"></script>

Comment: Am confident that it will works.. cause we are using this in our current project

Comment: which cordova version is u are using?

Comment: I'm using Cordova-3.0.0

Comment: Try this.

For instance, your "deviceready" callback:

document.addEventListener("offline", function() {
    alert("No internet connection");
}, false);